# R: Cannot find "function" in when passing ... to lapply?

Tags: r

I want to implement another version of `lapply` function that allows me to specify whether to run in parallel. The code is like this:

```
papply <- function(x,fun,...,
  parallel=FALSE,parallel.options=list(mode="socket",cpus=2),
  integrate=rbind,convert=NULL) {
  if(parallel) {
    require(parallelMap)
    do.call(parallelStart,parallel.options)
    result <- parallelLapply(x,fun,...)
    parallelStop()
  } else {
    result <- lapply(x,fun,...)
  }
  if(is.function(integrate)) {
    result <- do.call(integrate,result)
  }
  if(is.function(convert)) {
    result <- convert(result)
  }
  return(result)
}
```

If `parallel=TRUE`, I use `parallelLapply()` in `{parallelMap}` package, otherwise I use ordinary `lapply` function. In both methods, the vector/list I try to map is `x` and the mapping function is `fun`. Since `fun` may have more than one parameters, I use `...` to pass additional arguments to `fun`.

However, if no additional arguments are specified, like

```
papply(1:5,function(i,x){return(data.frame(a=i,b=i+1))})
```

It works fine and returns correct values:

```
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6
```

But if additional arguments are specified, like

```
papply(1:5,function(i,x){return(data.frame(a=i,b=i+x))},x=1)
```

It does not work out but reports an error like

```
 Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'fun' of mode 'function' was not found 
4 get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) 
3 match.fun(FUN) 
2 lapply(x, fun, ... = ...) at utils.R#37
1 papply(1:5, function(i, x) {
    return(data.frame(a = i, b = i + x))
}, x = 1)
```

I don't know why this error occurs. How can I resolve the error and make the function work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to a positional matching and argument naming issue.

`x` is formal argument of `papply`, therefore, when you name it in

```
papply(1:5, function(i, x) {return(data.frame(a=i, b=i+x))}, x=1)
```

This means that `1:5` is matched as `fun` --> hence the error.

In the current form of your function it is impossible for `R` to know that when you denote `x=1` that
you want this to be considered in the `...` component.

See the `MoreArgs` argument to `mapply` as an approach that might be useful.

Comment: The error indeed indicates that `1:5` is matches as `fun`, but why this could happen?

Comment: @KunRen - `papply` has two named arguments `x` and `fun`. you have named `x` in your call to `papply`. Positional matching then matches the first unnamed argument with the first formal argument yet to have a value. Therefore `1:5` is matched as `fun`. Change the function definition so that you don't have the same argument names in both functions and you should be fine.

Comment: @mnei - Yes, it really works after I change `x` to `.x` and `fun` to `.fun`. It's so tricky to name the arguments when `...` appears. Thanks!