# replace nested loop with expand.grid and call inner function with multiple arguments

Tags: r

I want to use `rollapply` function with various combinations of `width`, `by` and `FUN` arguments (`width` and `by` should have same value). I've inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-arguments-from-e) and created following code which is working but it has nothing to do with `rollapply` so far, it just demonstrates how to pass several arguments to function inside `apply`:

```
> dframe   <- expand.grid(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3))
> testFunc <- function(a, b) a^2 + b
> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) testFunc(x[1], x[2]))
[1]  2  5 10  3  6 11  4  7 12
> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) x[1]^2 + x[2])
[1]  2  5 10  3  6 11  4  7 12
> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) (x[1]^2 + x[2]))
[1]  2  5 10  3  6 11  4  7 12
> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) {x[1]^2 + x[2]})
[1]  2  5 10  3  6 11  4  7 12
```

My final solution is here, but this is not working:

```
> dframe   <- expand.grid(c(1,2,3), c(median, mean))
> testFunc <- function(a, b) rollapply(mtcars, width = a, by = a, FUN = b, align="left")

> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) testFunc(x[1], x[2]))
 Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'b' of mode 'function' was not found

> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) rollapply(mtcars, width = x[1], by = x[1], FUN = x[2], align="left"))
 Error in match.fun(FUN) : 'x[2]' is not a function, character or symbol
```

When I call `testFunc` directly everything is working fine so I guess the problem is that `apply` is not able to collect the results somehow:

```
> testFunc(10,mean)
       mpg cyl   disp    hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs  am gear carb
[1,] 20.37 5.8 208.61 122.8 3.538 3.1280 18.581 0.6 0.3  3.6  2.5
[2,] 19.89 6.6 259.25 149.6 3.552 3.6689 18.301 0.4 0.3  3.4  2.9
[3,] 20.39 6.2 228.25 152.6 3.654 2.8633 16.914 0.3 0.5  3.9  2.6

> class(testFunc(10,mean))
[1] "matrix"
```

I've tried also debug `testFunc` and call it from `apply` and seems that arguments are passed correctly:

```
> debug(testFunc)
> apply(dframe, 1, function(x) testFunc(x[1], x[2]))
debugging in: testFunc(x[1], x[2])
debug: rollapply(mtcars, width = a, by = a, FUN = b, align = "left")

Browse[2]> print(a)
$Var1
[1] 1

Browse[2]> print(b)
$Var2
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x08244ffc>
<environment: namespace:stats>

Browse[2]> n
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'b' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Questions:

1. What is error saying and what I'm doing wrong?
2. How can I replace nested loop with `expand.grid` and call inner
   function with multiple arguments?
3. How to return list of matrices using `*apply` family of functions?

PS: I guess it would be easy to achieve this using two nested loops but I'm wondering if there is R-way.

PPS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869534/r-cannot-find-function-in-when-passing-to-lapply) is answer regarding similar error (`object 'b' of mode 'function' was not found`) with the conclusion that `b` (in my case) conflicts with the named arguments with other function. But I cannot see this problem in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that `df <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)` and we apply `apply(df, 1, function(x) fun(x))`. Then the two passed arguments `x` are *vectors* `c(1, 3)` and `c(2, 4)`.

However, when `df <- expand.grid(c(1,2,3), c(median, mean))` and `apply(df, 1, function(x) fun(x))` is done, we can no longer store, e.g., `1` and `median` to a single vector because they are of too different types. Then `x` happens to be a *list*, e.g., `x <- list(1, median)`. Then, doing `x[1]` or `x[2]` does not give `1` and `median` as desired; instead these are lists with a single element (hence the error `object 'b' of mode 'function' was not found`). This can actually be seen in your debugging example.

So, here are some ways to use `apply` in your case:

1) do not modify `testFunc` but recognize that a list is passed by `apply`; in that case `do.call` helps, but it also cares about the names of the columns of `df`, so I also use `unname`:

```
apply(unname(df), 1, do.call, what = testFunc)
```

2) same as 1) but without `do.call`:

```
apply(dframe, 1, function(x) testFunc(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
```

3) `testFunc` redefined to have a single argument:

```
testFunc <- function(a) rollapply(mtcars, width = a[[1]], by = a[[1]], FUN = a[[2]], align="left")
apply(dframe, 1, testFunc)
```

Comment: Great answer, another option might be `Vectorize(testFunc)(dframe[[1]],dframe[[2]])`

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: is there any debugging techniques that are helpful with solving those problems?

Comment: @WakanTanka, I must admit that I do not use many debugging tools in general (which might be not a great thing), but I would find something like `apply(dframe, 1, function(x) browser())` sufficient in this case. What you did is equally good, you just needed to recognize that `$Var1` stands for a name of a list element rather than a name of a vector element, and that `rollapply` does not accept lists. You might find `traceback` informative too, since it shows that the error occurs at `get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)`.